# "Quello" or "quel"? What is the difference?

Tags: word-usage, difference, pronouns

> Non ho detto quello

Can I use "quel" instead? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Related question: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5690/why-questanno-but-questo-autunno

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't say *"Non ho detto quel"*.

When *quello* is used as a pronoun, only the form *quello* is possible.
When it is used as an adjective, you must follow the same rule used for the articles il/lo. Il -> quel / lo -> quello.

Examples:

*prendi quello straccio (lo straccio)*

*prendi quel gatto (il gatto)*

*guarda quell'uomo (l'uomo)*

*guarda quello*

The same rule applies to the plural form *quei/quegli*.